# PowerShell: Pester Unit Test with Before/After Blocks

Tags: powershell, pester

I'm learning to do Unit Tests with Pester and I am having a strange problem with the Before/After blocks. My Unit Test code is below:

```
 Describe "Before/After Blocks" {

        Context "BeforeEach/AfterAll" {

            BeforeAll {
                $value = 0
                Write-Host "->Initial value is $value"
            }

            BeforeEach {
                $value++
            }

            It "value is 1" {
                $value | Should -Be 1
            }

            It "value is 2" {
                $value | Should -Be 2
            }

            It "value is 3" {
                $value | Should -Be 3
            }

            AfterAll {
                Write-Host "->Final value is $value"
            }
        }
    }
```

Well, as you can see in the code, my purpose is to initializate a variable and see how it gets incremented by the BeforeEach block. This is the output:

> Context BeforeEach/AfterAll
>
> ->Initial value is 0
>
> ```
> [+] value is 1 
>
> [+] value is 2 
>
> [+] value is 3
> ```
>
> ->Final value is 0

The variable is initialized to 0 and before any It Block it's incrementing cause the assertions didn't fail. But the AfterAll block says the variable value is 0, the initial value and not 3 as I expect.

Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

The problem seems to be to be that the `AfterAll` block has its own scope (which I agree is a bit odd). You can get the result you expect by using global variables, although this isn't particularly great practice:

```
Describe "Before/After Blocks" {

    Context "BeforeEach/AfterAll" {

        BeforeAll {
            $global:value = 0
            Write-Host "->Initial value is $value"
        }

        BeforeEach {
            $global:value++
        }

        It "value is 1" {
            $global:value | Should -Be 1
        }

        It "value is 2" {
            $global:value | Should -Be 2
        }

        It "value is 3" {
            $global:value | Should -Be 3
        }

        AfterAll {
            Write-Host "->Final value is $global:value"
        }
    }
}
```